# Need Hashtable and Arraylist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, windows-phone-7, assembly-references

I am trying to use someone else's C# classes in my Windows 7 Phone app.  The classes use objects of type Hashtable.

The file in question has

```
using System.Collections;
```

at the top, so I'm assuming that's the Hashtable object it wants.

When I try to build my solution, I get errors that the type or namespace name 'Hashtable' could not be found, are you missing a using directive or assembly reference.

In Microsoft's documentation of Hashtable, I see it says Assembly: mscorlib

But if I try to add mscorlib via Project>Add Reference, VS says it can't add it because it is automatically referenced by the build system.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The non-generic collections, including `ArrayList` and `HashTable`, are not included in Silverlight.
These classes are hold-overs from .Net 1.0 (which didn't have generics) and should not be used in new code.

Instead, you should use the generic collections—`List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 10):

You have a few options:

1. Change your import to `using System.Collections.Generic;` and change every use of a `HashTable` to `Dictionary<>` and `ArrayList` to `List<>`.
2. You *might* be able to get away with:

   `using HashTable = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, object>;`
   `using ArrayList = System.Collections.Generic.List<object>;`
   Note that any future maintainer will hate you for doing this.
3. But it's better to refactor the code to use the generic collections properly.
4. Create a class `Hashtable` in a namespace `System.Collections`, implement `IDictionary<object, object>` by forwarding everything to an inner `Dictionary<object, object>` and implement the necessary changes in behavior (locking, missing keys, etc.); Create an `ArrayList` by encapsulation `List<object>`. (suggested by henon)

Comment: #2 is a horrible idea.  It would work, though, except that you need fully-qualified typenames.

Comment: @SLaks: You might not have noticed, but I have 3 ideas. Which one's horrible? Also, I'm not sure what you mean needs to be fully qualified.

Comment: The `using` statements need fully-qualified typenames, unless placed separately inside the `namespace`.

Comment: SLkaks: Good point. It's almost certainly the case that code old enough to use the old collection classes would have the `using` list outside the `namespace`.

Comment: +1 for the abominable #2 suggestion and then pointing out that anyone looking at it in the future may well wish you eviscerated

Comment: Idea #4 that works very well: create a class Hashtable in a namespace System.Collections, implement IDictionary<string, object> by forwarding everything to an inner Dictionary<string, object> and implement the indexer so that it does not fail when the key is not present in the inner dict.

Answer (score 2):

There are different mscorlibs depending on which .NET framework you are using. If you look in the "Other Versions" dropdown on the MSDN page, you will see `Hashtable` is not a part of Silverlight. You will need to use a `Dictionary<Object, Object>` (or ideally more strongly typed keys and value types)

[image: Hashtable is not in Silverlight]

[image: But Dictionary is]

Answer (score 1):

System.Collection is a legacy of first version of .Net - no generic types.

To fix your code use Dictorany class which is a hashtable at heart,
and List insted of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me changing:

Hashtable for  `Dictionary<object, object>`

NameValueCollection for `Dictionary<object, object>`

Other problem I encoutered is Encoding.ASCII is not defined either, I sorted that with a function a stackoverflow lad wrote:

```
public static byte[] StringToAscii(string s) {
    byte[] retval = new byte[s.Length];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < s.Length; ++ix) {
        char ch = s[ix];
        if (ch <= 0x7f) retval[ix] = (byte)ch;
        else retval[ix] = (byte)'?';
    }
    return retval;
}
```

credits here:

[ASCIIEncoding In Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022281/asciiencoding-in-windows-phone-7)

So finally to return the ASCII this is what to do:

return StringToAscii(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(result.ToArray()));