# Encoding.ASCII.GetString() in Windows Phone Platform

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encoding

```
byte[] tagData = GetTagBytes(tagID, out tiffDataType, out numberOfComponents);
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tagData);
```

With windows phone platform, the framework doesn't support `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` method.

I used to get help from Passant's post [ASCIIEncoding In Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022281/asciiencoding-in-windows-phone-7/4022893#4022893) befroe. But it only convert `string` to `byte[]`, now I need to convert `byte[]` into `string`.

Any Help would be nice~

Comment: Are you sure you REALLY need ASCII? 90% of the users that ask ASCII really want UTF-8

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858196/1028230) not work? You should/might (?) have a `GetString(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` method where you can use `GetString(tagData, 0, tagData.Length)`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to understand how [Hans' code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022281/asciiencoding-in-windows-phone-7/4022893#4022893) works, you'll easily come up with the reverse conversion:

```
public static string AsciiToString(byte[] bytes) { 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length); 
        foreach(byte b in bytes) {
            sb.Append(b<=0x7f ? (char)b : '?'); 
        } 
        return sb.ToString(); 
    }
```

You can also use LINQ but a nice solution is available only on .NET 4.0:

```
string AsciiToString(byte[] bytes)
{
  return string.Concat( bytes.Select(b => b <= 0x7f ? (char)b : '?') );
}
```

The unfortunate lack of the [String.Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828.aspx) overload in former versions of the framework forces you to use the somewhat ugly and inefficient:

```
string AsciiToString(byte[] bytes)
{
  return string.Concat( 
    ( bytes.Select(b => (b <= 0x7f ? (char)b : '?').ToString()) )
    .ToArray()
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. As I just a beginer for c#, lots confuse me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have ASCII (so <= 7f) you can simply cast the single bytes as char.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tagData.Length);
foreach (var b in tagData)
{
    sb.Append((char)b);
}

var str = sb.ToString();
```

I'll add that probably what you need is `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tagData)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToBase64String Method (byte[]) returns string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(VS.95).aspx

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Serge - appTranslator, I created an overloaded implementation that fully mimics Encoding.ASCII.GetString for silverlight

```
    public static string EncodingASCIIGetString(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(count);

        for(int i = index; i<(index+count); i++)
        {
            sb.Append(bytes[i] <= 0x7f ? (char)bytes[i] : '?');             
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Havent tried it though. Feel free to edit