# how to Covert encoding UTF-8 String in Windows phone Application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, encoding, utf-8

well. about in my windows phone application :

The server-side response data to the client. All data sent from the server using the UTF-8 encoding windows phone application how to parse server side after UTF-8 encoded data?

anybody have some suggestion?>

Comment: Can't really understand the question... the data is sent in UTF-8, so what is the problem? Windows Phone is already able to work with UTF-8 without any problems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a byte array to work with, try the following:

Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3(v=vs.95).aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: hi prish. i know what do you mean. but all data response from server is utf-8 encoding string . that why i ask how convert ?

Comment: So I am not sure what you mean. An example would be helpful.