# Encoding.ASCII not available in Silverlight is there a alternative?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, encoding, ascii

I have the following line of code for a Windows forms application:

```
return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(chars.ToArray());
```

This line worked fine, but today I was trying my code on the Windows Phone/Silverlight framework and the:

```
Encoding.ASCII
```

Library does not exist there. Is there any (simple) way to do the same thing but with a Silverlight library?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022281/asciiencoding-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022281/asciiencoding-in-windows-phone-7) solution? It looks like there is an easy way to achieve it. cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Encoding.UTF8 - Silverlight is unicode only.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using Encoding.UTF8 will solve your problem, but you can always use the [Silverlight Encoding Generator](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) and get any encoding you'd like!

Comment: Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII") will throw an error though