# Will ASCIITools.StringToAscii do the same job as Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes

Tags: c#, character-encoding, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASCIIEncoding In Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022281/asciiencoding-in-windows-phone-7)

I am working with Windows Phone 8, and I have noticed that Encoding.ASCII doesn't exist in .NET for Windows Phone, but there is a class called ASCIITools, which contains a method called StringToAscii. which returns a byte array and accepts a string.

I ask because I am trying to convert some code which initially gets a character array from a string like this:

```
char[] myCharArray = blah.Substring(aaa, bbb).ToCharArray();
```

And then gets the byte array from the char array by passing it into the GetBytes method:

```
byte[] blah = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myCharArray, 0, myCharArray.Length);
```

It looks like this class will allow me to go directly from a string to a byte array like so:

```
byte[] blah = ASCIITools.StringToAscii(blah.Substring(aaa, bbb));
```

Will this work?

Comment: Probably using Encoding.UTF8 will solve your problem, but you can always use the [Silverlight Encoding Generator][1] and get any encoding you'd like!


  [1]: http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator

Comment: Test it out! Messagebox.Show(Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(myCharArray, 0, myCharArray.Length) + Enviroment.NewLine + ASCIITools.StringToAscii(myCharArray.ToString());