# Encryption with an ASCII Encoding (ASP.NET) vs Encryption with a UTF-8 Encoding (Silverlight)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, encryption, utf-8, ascii

I currently have a set of AES Encryption/Decryption functions that I use in ASP.NET for all of my cryptographic needs. I then pass these data in apps back and forth to another secure application that I have no control over. Everything is sent in strings, and the strings are sent to and from these apps with an ASCII encoding.

Now I am working with a pre-existing Silverlight app, where I have a need to add encrypt/decrypt functionality to data, but I will still be sending to this other secure application (over which I have no control) that uses ASCII encoding. Since Silverlight uses UTF-8, this seems like it might be a problem. I know enough about encodings to know how ASCII and UTF-8 are alike and different (0 through 127 are the same in each, but UTF-8 has many more characters). Are there any risks to encrypting/decrypting in UTF-8 on my end if I am going to be sending/receiving data to/from an app that uses ASCII? (My app will not be using any non-standard characters before the encryption)

Also, should I:

1. Use a Service Reference in Silverlight that has my ASCII encryption/decryption functions? OR
2. Encrypt/Decrypt in UTF-8 inside Silverlight app, no service reference required?

Comment: Why are you using ASCII instead of UTF-8?

Comment: The third party I said about (above) uses that encoding, and since they're pretty inflexible and difficult to deal with, and it's readily available in .NET, so did we.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while it's bad from an i18n perspective, if can be reasonably sure that your input is going to be only in the range of normal ascii characters, you shouldn't have a problem.

You can add the code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022893/1904979) to give you some extra protection -- converting non-ASCII safe UTF-8 characters to a '?', returning a byte array you can feed into your encryption method.

Comment: So there's no chance that my UTF-8 encryption would result in a non-ASCII character in the encrypted string?

Comment: if you use the code in the link, it will guarantee that the plaintext passed into your encryption method is fully ASCII characters.  That said, it guarantees that by converting all non-ASCII characters to `?`, but if you don't have a lot of users trying to type weird unicode characters into your app, you should be fine.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but what if a non-ASCII character appears in the cipher text? Like if I have the string "dog", and encrypt it using UTF-8, couldn't it end up being something like "e45gØ"? That would cause the decryption to fail on the other end, even if I substituted the 'Ø' for a '?', right?

Comment: oh, well, you can get around that by not converting the cipher text from a byte array to a String directly.  Use something like base64 to encode your ciphertext

Comment: Ah, gotcha. THAT was the step I was missing when trying to think of it. Thanks!