# Overwriting an extension method C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to create http requests to a webservice. One of the parameters length is very long running >100 K characters, so I figured I'll need to use the POST method (because of limitations on length of query string with GET). However, when I tried doing so I got an exception that the uri is too long. I downloaded their source code to find out why. Take a look at the following code:

```
querystring.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", p.Name.UrlEncode(), p.Value.UrlEncode());
```

Now the UrlEncode() method is an extension method available in StringExtensions.cs class and it's implementations is like so:

```
public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
    {
        return Uri.EscapeDataString(input);
    }
```

The problem is that Uri.EscapeDataString cannot process a string more than 65519 characters (see post - [Uri.EscapeDataString() - Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695208/uri-escapedatastring-invalid-uri-the-uri-string-is-too-long))

My problem can be solved if the UrlEncode extension method was implemented like this

```
public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
    {
        int limit = 65520;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int loops = input.Length / limit;

        for (int i = 0; i <= loops; i++)
        {
            if (i < loops)
            {
                sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(input.Substring(limit * i, limit)));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(input.Substring(limit * i)));
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

The issue is that I DON'T want to HAVE to modify the source code. Is there a way I can write my own extension method in MY source code such that when the third party code is trying to invoke UrlEncode() it ignores it's own extension method and instead calls my extension method??

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're appending the payload to the querystring to do a POST, you're doing it wrong...

Comment: I cannot speak to whether this is the correct approach or not, but this is OSS, so you could always make the change to the source and make a pull request. At bare minimum, you could always create a custom version

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully, there's no way that I know of.  The extension method `s.UrlEncode()` is basically syntactic sugar for

```
StringExtensions.UrlEncode(s);
```

Since this method is static, there's no way to "override" it.  In addition, it's bound to that method at *compile* time, so there's no way to redirect it to a different method at run time.

It should NOT be allowed, either.  If it were, You could create an "override" it to format your C drive!.

If YOU want to use a different version, you could create a new extension method with a different name, or figure out a way to shorten your parameter lengths. :)

Answer (score 1):

one solution would be to extend the existing Uri class with [hiding through inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - you should inherit the existing Uri class and then override with the **new** operator the desired method. This way you will change the default behaviour without modifying original code. Code example:

```
public class A
{
    public int Get1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int Get2()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    // override A's Get1
    public new int Get1()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

and the output of the call:

```
var b = new B();
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", b.Get1(), b.Get2()));
```

would be:

```
2 - 100
```

and not 1 - 100!

Hope this helps.

Regards,
P.

Comment: Only problem with this, is that if the third party decides to downcast it to `Uri` (or if it gets passed into _any_ code that takes a `Uri`, including _any_ methods within `Uri` that might leverage it) then the _original_ `UrlEncode` method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401165/182654) to see how to do a `POST` using RestSharp.  The payload goes in the message body, not in the query string.