# How do i pass a string variable to another page without using Uri in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uri

The string I want to pass from one WP page to another contains the character '#'. So when I pass this string using Uri, the rest of the string starting from '#' gets truncated which causes a json parse error. So how else can I pass this string? I don't want to modify the string and pass it as the downloaded string varies from user to user.

Here is my code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml?jsonData=" + text, UriKind.Relative));
```

Here is my json string contained in "text" variable:

```
{"name":"RALPH K. TELL","course":"","attendence":[{"name":"OBJECT ORIENTED ANALYSIS AND DESIGN","type":"Theory","conducted":"14","present":"14"},{"name":"C#AND.NET FRAMEWORK","type":"Theory","conducted":"17","present":"16"}]}
```

Here is how I get the value in the next page:

```
String jdata = NavigationContext.QueryString["jsonData"];
```

Comment: Did you try `Uri.EscapeDataString(...)` the data you want to pass?

Comment: @RowlandShaw No I hadn't. Just did and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of your query strings contain characters that are considered invalid in a Uri what you're doing will fail, as you've discovered. You need to use [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) to escape any illegal characters first. 
Change the code you've posted to the following:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml?jsonData=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(text), UriKind.Relative));
```

Have a look at these threads [Uri.EscapeDataString() - Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695208)

[HttpUtility.UrlEncode in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573290)

Hope it helps!