# size limit workaround for FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, .net

I'm receiving the error:

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.
```

The problem is with this line:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
```

Upon researching this I've learned it is because of a size limitation of the class **FormUrlEncodedContent**. But I'm not sure how I can workaround this? See code below:

```
 public Token RequestToken(string username, int businessID, string requestXml)
    {
        var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "username", username }, { "businessID", businessID.ToString() }, { "authenticator", requestXml } };
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);          

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PostAsync("Token", content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>().Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695208/uri-escapedatastring-invalid-uri-the-uri-string-is-too-long/10755250#10755250)

Comment: I'm a bit confused with by the example in the provided link. That example is using a string and I have a dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

If your request is larger use multipart/form-data instead:

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    foreach (var keyValuePair in data)
    {
        content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
    }

    // send POST request
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return client.PostAsync(identifier.IsirUrl + uri, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's adapt your existing code to the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695208/uri-escapedatastring-invalid-uri-the-uri-string-is-too-long/10755250#10755250)

```
int limit = 2000;

StringContent content = new StringContent(postData.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, nxt) => {

    StringBuilder sbInternal = new StringBuilder();

    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        sb.Append("&");
    }

    int loops = nxt.Value.Length / limit;

    for (int i = 0; i <= loops; i++)
    {
        if (i < loops)
        {
            sbInternal.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(nxt.Value.Substring(limit * i, limit)));
        }
        else
        {
            sbInternal.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(nxt.Value.Substring(limit * i)));
        }
    }

    return sb.Append(nxt.Key + "=" + sbInternal.ToString());
}).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Quick walkthrough that code: Implode each key-value pair (parameter) in your dictionary with LINQ's Aggregate using a limit-proof URL encoding method.

The length of string parameter of `Uri.EscapteDataString` [method is limited to 32766 characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Uri_EscapeDataString_System_String_), the `limit` local property must be 32766 to avoid unnecessary iteration.

This is how you should create you content now, instead of using FormUrlEncodedContent

Hopefully it'll help.