# ASP.NET submit a GET varialble with a URL inside

Tags: c#, .net, url, urlencode

I have a situation where I need to put a url inside a GET variable.
for example:

> 'http://www.site.com/StepOne?b=1&afterUrl=**http://www.site.com/StepTwo?someVar=text&b=1**'

In this case, when I am at `StepOne` the b param value will be `1,1` and not `1` as expected.
the `afterUrl` param will be:

> 'http://www.site.com/StepTwo?someVar=text'

instead of this:

> 'http://www.site.com/StepTwo?someVar=text&**b=1**'

How do I isolate the `afterUrl` param so its own GET variables won't effect the entire URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the `afterUrl` URL parameter, be sure to [`UrlEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx) the value.

e.g.

```
var url = String.Format("http://www.site.com/StepOne?b={0}&afterUrl={1}", b, Server.UrlEncode(afterUrl));
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` for the `AfterURL`

(**EDIT** or `Server.URLEncode()` as others have pointed out)

```
"http://www.site.com/StepOne?b=1&afterUrl=" + 
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(http://www.site.com/StepTwo?someVar=text&b=1");
```

Then when you finally hit the "StepOne" page you can use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(AfterURL variable name)`. From there you can Response.redirect or whatever you want with the preserved after url.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why and how, so those reading gain an understanding of what they are doing?

Comment: The problem with `HttpUtility` is that it's in System.Web.dll, which is usually only available for ASP.NET projects.

Comment: @ToddBFisher Ummm... Isn't `Server` an instance of `HttpServerUtility`, which is *also* only available in `System.Web.dll`?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I never put the two together, thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Use Server.UrlEncode on someVar to escape out it's querystring values before putting it in the link.  You may need to use Server.UrlDecode on the other side to convert it back to the original characters.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you need to URL encode the `afterUrl` param (actually, you should URL encode all parameters passed to a server), which will turn "http://www.site.com/StepTwo?someVar=text&b=1" into "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2FStepTwo%3FsomeVar%3Dtext%26b%3D1", which won't affect the set of parameters.  Almost any server framework on the market will automatically decode that back into the string "http://www.site.com/StepTwo?someVar=text&b=1", or at least give you a function to do so yourself.

**EDIT:**

As [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840762/how-do-you-urlencode-without-using-system-web) shows, it is possible to URL encode a string without using System.Web, using `System.Net.Uri.EscapeDataString()`.