# C# Code URl Issues

Tags: c#

Hello guys i am working on a Database an i am getting stuck i have a code to go to a site, log me in , and then open a new tab that would open a transaction page but the link i have has a space and when chrome gets it it searches only the first part.

Here is the code.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", " http://database.spincap.com/transaction/search/#entity/SCAP-3 LLC/review_capital/1323");

That is the one i am testing and when i reun that i get the following results

[image]

Can someone help me please

after that i am turning the code into

```
        // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", " http://database.spincap.com/transaction/search/#entity/" + PendingTran_Entityname + "/review_capital/" + PendingTran_ID+"");
```

Comment: You probably have to encode the uri, e.g. `SCAP-3 LLC` should be `SCAP-3%20LLC`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the parameter between double quotation marks:

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "\"http://database.spincap.com/transaction/search/#entity/SCAP-3 LLC/review_capital/1323\"");
```

Without the double quotation marks the space character is a delimiter for command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to encode URL

For example:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("YourUrlGoesHere")
```

See more informatoin on this topic and use method that suits you the most: [How do you UrlEncode without using System.Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840762/how-do-you-urlencode-without-using-system-web)