# How do I make a string Unicode and put in it Arabic text and use the text?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I want to copy the text from a textbox in the WebBrowser control and navigate to a link with the text of the textbox in the link, it works, but the Arabic letters become question marks...

Comment: Did you check required font is available in the System? If not try installing the font.

Comment: When I set a breaking point and hover the mouse over the name of the string, it is shown correctly, but when i use the text to navigate to a website, the Google search appears for questionamarks, what I do is: webBrowserPics.Navigate("google.com//search?site=&tbm=isch&q=" + query);

Comment: Encoding your `query` using `System.Uri.EscapeDataString()` as mentioned in [How do you UrlEncode without using System.Web](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7878050/205233) might be worth a try. If you'd post sample text I could have tried for you.

Comment: My source code is a 5 KB simple download, it's in the website of my useful program that opens a Google Translate window when F1 is pressed:

sites.google.com/site/windowsprogramfortranslation/

Comment: if u refuse to download my program, what should I write in the Navigate text?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **language for the Non Unicode programs** to arabic I had similar issues with programs displaying question marks instead of arabic characters and this resolved my issue to do that  you need to go  to
**Control Panel**> **Clock,Language,Region**>**Change date,time,or number Format** >in the **administrative** tab click **change system locale** and select **Arabic**

[Changing the language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgjCv.png)

**Note**:you may experience problems with other Non Unicode programs that use special charterers for example the è will be displayed as an Arabic charecter

Comment: I don't think this is the case, when I navigate to:
google.com//search?site=&tbm=isch&q‌​=عربي
it works, but when i navigate to it from a string in C#, it shown questionmarks, it's about making the string store info as Unicode

Answer (score 0):

solved with:
WebUtility.UrlEncode