# itext PDF link doesn't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, itext, microsoft-edge

I'm adding a link to a file from a pdf document (created with itext)
this way:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(fileName, font);
chunk.SetAnchor("./relative/path/to/file");
```

Link works great if I open document in Google Chrome or Adobe reader.
But it doesn't work if I open my PDF in Microsoft Edge.

Is it even possible to create a file link inside pdf with itext that will work in Microsoft Edge? If yes, then how?

Comment: I just tested around a bit. It appears that Edge does not accept relative URIs here, only complete, absolute ones including the protocol, e.g. "file:///C:/Users/mkl/Documents/test.png"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it even possible to create a file link inside pdf with itext that will work in Microsoft Edge?
>
> If yes, then how?

Having done some tests it appears that Edge does not support relative links in PDF documents.

It does support absolute links, though, given the full URI, e.g.

```
chunk = new Chunk("Only ASCII chars in target. Full path.");
chunk.SetAnchor("file:///C:/Repo/GitHub/testarea/itext5/target/test-outputs/annotate/Attachments/1.png");
doc.Add(new Paragraph(chunk));
```

In contrast to other PDF viewers (Adobe Reader, Chrome, cf. [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302963/1729265) in this context) it does **not** support URL encoding of special characters like Cyrillic ones:

```
chunk = new Chunk("Cyrillic chars in target. URL-encoded. Full path. NOT WORKING");
chunk.SetAnchor("file:///C:/Repo/GitHub/testarea/itext5/target/test-outputs/annotate/" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("Вложения") + "/1.png");
doc.Add(new Paragraph(chunk));
```

But it does support the special characters in UTF-8 encoding. As UTF-8 `PdfString` encoding is a PDF-2.0 feature and iText 5 does not support PDF-2.0, one has to cheat a bit to inject strings in UTF-8 encoding here:

```
chunk = new Chunk("Cyrillic chars in target. Action manipulated. Full path.");
chunk.SetAnchor("XXX");
action = (PdfAction)chunk.Attributes[Chunk.ACTION];
action.Put(PdfName.URI, new PdfString(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("file:///C:/Repo/GitHub/testarea/itext5/target/test-outputs/annotate/Вложения/1.png")));
doc.Add(new Paragraph(chunk));
```

<sub>*Tested with Edge 41.16299.666.0*</sub>