# How to encode the plus (+) symbol in a URL

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gmail, urlencode, html-encode

The URL link below will open a new Google mail window.  The problem I have is that Google replaces all the plus (+) signs in the email body with blank space.  It looks like it only happens with the `+` sign.  How can I remedy this?  (I am working on a ASP.NET web page.)

https://mail.google.com/mail?view=cm&tf=0&to=someemail@somedomain.com&su=some subject&body=Hi there+Hello there

(In the body email, "Hi there+Hello there" will show up as "Hi there Hello there")

Comment: This is a top search engine hit for "site:stackoverflow.com plus URL encode link". This is acceptable, though there must be an older canonical question somewhere, after nearly 3 years in. For instance, one that is language and framework-agnostic (in case that is the real question, not how it specifically achieved).

Comment: A corresponding [one for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/) (framework-agnostic).

Comment: A corresponding [one for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript) (framework-agnostic).

Comment: What is the language and framework-agnostic Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

The `+` character has a special meaning in [the query segment of] a URL => it means whitespace:  . If you want to use the literal `+` sign there, you need to URL encode it to `%2b`:

```
body=Hi+there%2bHello+there
```

Here's an example of how you could properly generate URLs in .NET:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("https://mail.google.com/mail");

var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
values["view"] = "cm";
values["tf"] = "0";
values["to"] = "someemail@somedomain.com";
values["su"] = "some subject";
values["body"] = "Hi there+Hello there";

uriBuilder.Query = values.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.ToString());
```

The result:

> https://mail.google.com:443/mail?view=cm&tf=0&to=someemail%40somedomain.com&su=some+subject&body=Hi+there%2bHello+there

Comment: The RFC clearly says that the + sign can be used unencoded, and also if it had to be encoded, there is no reason to turn it into a "space" character. Maybe you can point us to a proper document of a standard mentioning what is that of translating a + symbol into a space symbol and vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah what are you talking about? I've never seen an RFC or anything that says + means spaces....

Comment: **Warning:** If you use the `Uri` property of `UriBuilder` you will get a bad result.  `uriBuilder.Uri.ToString()` in your example would return `Hi+there+Hello+there`.  Using `uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri` seems to work correctly and http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120429/1931573 suggests this is fixed in .NET 4.5.  As far as RFC goes, the HTML 4 spec says the URL querystring is of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which itself defines (+) as meaning space.  So it's not an RFC but is part of the HTML standard.

Comment: @freedrull but it really works this way - that shows the number of upvotes

Comment: Note that IIS considers this "double encoding" and will often block a url loaded this way with this error:

HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: @freedrull According to the [.NET 5 documentation for HTTPUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-5.0), "The UrlEncode method converts each space character to a plus character (+)" (which the result in the answer confirms). According to the [PHP documentation for urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), "Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character".

Comment: @PabloAriel According to a [W3C document addressing URLs](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html): "Within the query string, the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space. Therefore, real plus signs must be encoded. This method was used to make query URIs easier to pass in systems which did not allow spaces."

Comment: This helped me very much! I needed to encode + sign in generated vCard in PHP the normal + sign didnt work. Thank you!

Comment: @PabloAriel No the RFC says that the + sign is a reserved character. See [RFC 3986 section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)

Answer (score 36):

If you want a plus `+` symbol in the body you have to encode it as `%2B`.

For example:
[Try this](https://mail.google.com/mail?view=cm&tf=0&to=someemail@somedomain.com&su=some%20subject&body=Hi%20there%2bHello%20there)

Comment: Literally as `%2B`?

Comment: Yes, `%2B` is what you want!

Answer (score 13):

In order to encode a `+` value using JavaScript, you can use the `encodeURIComponent` function.

Example:

```js
var url = "+11";
var encoded_url = encodeURIComponent(url);
console.log(encoded_url)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 5):

Just to add this to the list:

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("Hi there+Hello there") // Hi%20there+Hello%20there
Uri.EscapeDataString("Hi there+Hello there") // Hi%20there%2BHello%20there
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34189188/98491

Usually you want to use `EscapeDataString` which does it right.

Answer (score 4):

It's safer to always percent-encode all characters except those defined as "unreserved" in RFC-3986.

unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

So, percent-encode the plus character and other special characters.

The problem that you are having with pluses is because, according to RFC-1866 (HTML 2.0 specification), paragraph 8.2.1. subparagraph 1., "The form field names and values are escaped: space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped"). This way of encoding form data is also given in later HTML specifications, look for relevant paragraphs about application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 3):

Generally if you use .NET API's - `new Uri("someproto:with+plus").LocalPath` or `AbsolutePath` will keep plus character in URL. (Same `"someproto:with+plus"` string)

but `Uri.EscapeDataString("with+plus")` will escape plus character and will produce `"with%2Bplus"`.

Just to be consistent I would recommend to always escape plus character to `"%2B"` and use it everywhere - then no need to guess who thinks and what about your plus character.

I'm not sure why from escaped character `'+'` decoding would produce space character `' '` - but apparently it's the issue with some of components.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me on QRCode perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURLComponent

```
const email = "etsretrs+tesreti@tsiter.com"
const encodedEmail = encodeURIComponent(email)
const newurl = `https://something.com/test?email=${encodedEmail}`
```