# How to avoid that UriBuilder creates Uri with unencoded + sign in its query string?

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

I have some trouble with the UriBuilder and Uri classes in .Net. I want to build my Uri with a UriBuilder, and then use the resulting Uri. However, I cant get it to correctly encode the plus sign in its query string?

Here is a small code example:

```
var ub = new UriBuilder();
ub.Query = "t=a%2bc";
Console.WriteLine(ub.Uri.ToString());
```

This example gives me `http://localhost/?t=a+c`, but I would expect that the plus sign was encoded to %2b like this `http://localhost/?t=a%2bc` otherwise I cant use the url.

I could of course build a string instead, but I would prefer to use the strongly typed Uri if possible.

Comment: Pls see [Error with pymunk space.remove method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268599/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, this seems to be "fixed" in .NET 4.5.

This is the result of my testing in .NET **4.0**: (from the immediate window)

```
? ub.Uri.ToString()
"http://localhost/?t=a+c"
```

*But* in .NET **4.5**:

```
? ub.Uri.ToString()
"http://localhost/?t=a%2bc"
```

Which is what you are looking for.

Can you upgrade to 4.5? This would fix your problem.

If you cannot upgrade, let me know and I'll attempt to find a work around.

Comment: Interesting. Im on VS2010 right now but have an upgrade to 2012 planned soon (within a month or so). However, right now I need to fix the bug using 2010. See my answer for the temp workaround I ended up using. But I marked you as accepted because its the long term solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use AbsoluteUri instead of ToString():

```
var ub = new UriBuilder();
ub.Query = "t=a%2bc";
Console.WriteLine(ub.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

this gives the correct result:

```
http://localhost/?t=a%2bc
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a custom Uri class wrapping the Uri for now until we have the chance to update to VS2012/.Net4.5. Most Uris in the system Im working on are not created by newing Uris but instead with a Querybuilder method which means it was "easy" to swap that part to return a Uri2 instead of a Uri.

```
public class Uri2 : Uri
{
    public Uri2(Uri uri)
        : base(uri.ToString())
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var s = base.ToString();
        s = s.Replace("+", "%2b");
        return s;
    }
}
```