# how to prevent angular2 http library from removing special chars from login data?

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I'm trying to use http library to issue a login request to a specific api.
I'm getting a wrong credentials error because the data sent is encoded somehow and all the plus signs are changed to spaces.
so if I enter amani+salah@gamil.com as an email, the console.log logs it correctly but it's sent as amani salah@gmail.com in the formdata.
The same thing happens for any data, not just the email, so if a users's password has a + in it, the data sent will be changed to.

This is my code:

```
let email = 'xxxx@example.com';
let password = 'xxxx';
let body = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
console.log(body);
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let url = this.base_url + '/login';
this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers})
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    resolve(this.data);
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the string like shown in [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
let body = 'email='+encodeURIComponent('+email+'&password='+password);
```

Comment: could you please explain or add a link to why this happened in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450190/how-to-encode-the-plus-symbol-in-url "The + character has a special meaning in a url => it means whitespace."

Answer (score 0):

Plus sign it's not encoded correctly by angular, it's an known bug; see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058