# using + in the variables passed to a url

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to do a call to url

```
http://example.com/controller/action?var1=CD14+%20MDM%20in%20GM-CSF%203%20days%20then%203%20days%20IFN-%CE%B3&var2=56&var3=ENSG00000115415
```

If you look at var1 that I am passing value `'CD14+ MDM in GM-CSF 3 days then 3days IFN-γ'`.

When in the controller I try to get this var 1 using `request.params.get("var1")`, i get `'CD14  MDM in GM-CSF 3 days then 3days IFN-γ'` with missing + and instead getting extra space after CD14

How can I pass + in my variable in url

Answer (score 0):

This has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450219/2511541). It says that `+` needs to be encoded as `%2B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intended to use plus as a data component, instead of url component, You should pass `%2B` instead.

**Javascript :**

```js
var url = "http://example.com/controller/action?var1=CD14+%20MDM%20in%20GM-CSF%203%20days%20then%203%20days%20IFN-%CE%B3&var2=56&var3=ENSG00000115415";

//NOTE: this following wil lreplace all + to %2B
url = url.replace(/\+/g,"%2B");

console.log("new : ",url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try '%2B' (as other have stated).

But if you are in Javascript, you could just use the built-in method for doing URL encoding called "encodeURIComponent". Note you need that and not "encodeURI" which will not encode reserved characters like '+'. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Thanks for your help