# nestjs substitutes symbols in request body

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I'm trying to send a request to my Nestjs application, with just plain string in the request body, for example:

`test23+Se5+345`

Then in my application, I have a middleware, where I need to do something with this string.
The problem is when I access request body in middleware `const requestBody = Object.keys(req.body)[0];`, this string looks like this:

`test23 Se5 345`

All of the `+` symbols are substituted by

I don't have additional convertings before this, and I know that middleware runs first in the request lifecycle. I think maybe there is some issue with body-parser, but I don't know yet how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because symbol `+` is treated as space, so before send it, you need to encode your `+` characters to `%2b`. More here: [How to encode the plus (+) symbol in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450190/how-to-encode-the-plus-symbol-in-a-url)