# how to find special characters like + in laravel search query api

Tags: laravel

https://tulionsbloodbank.org/api/donors?blood_group=AB+&address=Pepsi cola

`get` route:

```
Route::get('/donors','Api\DonorController@filter');
```

Controller:

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    //$donorQuery = Donor::query();
    $donorQuery = Donor::where('status', 1);
  
    if ($request->has('address')) {
     $donorQuery->where('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->address . '%');
    }
   if ($request->has('blood_group')) {
    $donorQuery->where('blood_group', $request->blood_group);
   }
    $donorList = $donorQuery->get();
    $TotaldonorList = Donor::where('status', 1)->count();
  
  
    $donorList = $donorQuery->get();
    $data['donors']=$donorList;
    $data['message']='Donors List';
    $data['total'] = Donor::count();
    return response()->json($data, 200);

    return response()->json($donorList, 200);

}
```

My query can search address filed but unable to get blood group data due to special characters  AB+

Comment: You'll probably need to URL-escape the plus; `%2B`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode the plus (+) symbol in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450190/how-to-encode-the-plus-symbol-in-a-url)

Comment: what `var_dump($request->blood_group)` returns

Answer (score 0):

You should encode `blood_group` query param on client side in javascript like

```
encodeURIComponent(blood_group);
```

Then decode it on server side (in Controller) like

```
urldecode($request->blood_group);
```