# django rest framework is removing "+" from datetimes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple django get view:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def test_endpoint(request):
    print(request)
    print(request.GET)
```

The result of this -

```
<rest_framework.request.Request: GET '/api/test_endpoint?start=1969-12-31T19:00:00+05:00&end=2023-01-16T21:22:52-05:00'>

<QueryDict: {'start': ['1969-12-31T19:00:00 05:00'], 'end': ['2023-01-16T21:22:52-05:00']}>
```

If you notice `start` for some reason is cleansing out the `+` in the datetime. Thus causing an incorrectly formatted datetime object.  I have no interest in changing my formatting, but rather fixing why django rest framework is removing the `+`.  You can clearly see in the actual GET request that the `+` is properly in the string.

Any ideas on how to fix this so `start` value would be `'1969-12-31T19:00:00+05:00'` instead of `'1969-12-31T19:00:00 05:00'` without "fixing" it after the fact? (I want the `request.GET` object to be correct, I don't want to fix the values after retrieving them from `request.GET`)

Comment: In URLs, plus signs are translated to spaces.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/5450190/494134

Comment: Clients would need to use `%2B` instead, because `+` means a space there.