# nodejs express app route parameters cannot recognize +

Tags: node.js, express, query-string

I have below running in nodejs 16.18.x

```
app.get('/CheckPlan', (req, res) => {
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
var dataToSend;
console.log("1111", req.query.token);
}
```

calling this from postman http://localhost:3000/CheckPlan?key=C3363&token=abc+TI4

the problem is the + in token is missing. what i see is only 'abc T14'

anyone has any idea ?

not sure why the + is missing from the passed argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode the plus (+) symbol in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450190/how-to-encode-the-plus-symbol-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

From the [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) doc, we know Express framework uses the `qs` package as its default query parser.

> A very popular query string parser is the `qs` module, and this is used by default.

The default value of `query parser` application setting is `"extended"`, see [#app.settings.table](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table), it will use the `qs` module as its query parser.

Let's take a look the source code, `express` compile the query parse at this line [4.18.2/lib/utils.js#L200](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.18.2/lib/utils.js#L200)

The `parseExtendedQueryString` implementation:

```js
function parseExtendedQueryString(str) {
  return qs.parse(str, {
    allowPrototypes: true
  });
}
```

As you can see, it uses the [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) module to parse the query string.

Let's go back to your question, `?key=C3363&token=abc+TI4` query string is invalid in the first place because the `+` sign is special in a query string.

> `+` sign has a semantic meaning in the query string. It is used to represent a space.

For more information, see this question [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

So, if you want to keep the `+` sign as a part in the parsed value, you need to encode the query string using `encodeURIComponent` like this before sending the HTTP request:

```
const obj = qs.parse(`key=C3363&token=${encodeURIComponent('abc+TI4')}`)
console.log(obj); // {key: "C3363", token: "abc+TI4"}
```